# Top-level OverloadedLists literal

Tags: haskell, overloaded-lists

I've got a test suite for a refactoring exercise where I'd like it to be compatible with both `Data.List` and `Data.List.NonEmpty`. The exercise consists of a function `foo :: [Foo] -> Foo` and the test suite has some

```hs
data Case = Case
  { description :: String
  , input :: [Foo]
  , expected :: Foo
  }

cases :: [Case]
cases =
  [ Case { description = "blah blah"
         , input = [Foo 1, Foo 2, Foo 3]
         , expected = Foo 1
         }
  , ...
  ]
```

To make the test suite polymorphic with `OverloadedLists`, I tried

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}
...

data Case list = Case
  { description :: String
  , input :: list Foo
  , expected :: Foo
  }

cases =
  [ Case { description = "blah blah"
         , input = [Foo 1, Foo 2, Foo 3]
         , expected = Foo 1
         }
  , ...
  ]
```

but this gives me the error

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘GHC.Exts.Item (list0 Foo)’
                  with actual type ‘Foo’
      The type variable ‘list0’ is ambiguous
      ...
   |
50 |          , input = [Foo 1, Foo 2, Foo 3]
   |                     ^^^^^
```

I thought to move the `IsList list` constraint to the `Case` data type, like so

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}
...

data Case list where
  Case :: IsList list => String -> list Foo -> Foo -> Case list

cases =
  [ Case "blah blah" [Foo 1, Foo 2, Foo 3] (Foo 1), ... ]
```

but this gives me the error

```
    • Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘list’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the type ‘list Foo’
      In the definition of data constructor ‘Case’
      In the data declaration for ‘Case’
   |        
24 |   Case :: IsList list => String -> list Foo -> Foo -> Case list
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^
```

I'm not sure what the simplest approach here is. Any hints?

Comment: It should be `Case :: IsList (list Foo) => String -> list Foo -> Foo -> Case list`, since `IsList` takes a type with kind `*`, not `* -> *`..

Comment: But this will not fix the underlying problem, since the items of such overloaded lists are of type `Item`, and that is, although very common, not per se `Foo`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because the `Item` type of a `List (l Foo) => l` is not *per se* `Foo`. The extension makes abstraction of that, and thus it expects the elements of your list literal to be of type `Item (l Foo)`.

You can however add a type constraint that says that the items are indeed of type `Foo`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}

data Case list = Case
  { description :: String
  , input :: list Foo
  , expected :: Foo
  }

cases :: (IsList (l Foo), Item (l Foo) ~ Foo) => [Case l]
cases = [
    Case { description = "blah blah"
         , input = [Foo 1, Foo 2, Foo 3]
         , expected = Foo 1
         }
  ]
```

Here we thus say that the `Item (l Foo)` should be the same as `Foo`.

Comment: Ah, so this uncovered two misconceptions, one of which I was not aware. Thanks a bunch!